# How can I make a queue in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, express, logging, mongoose, queue

For context :

In my app Im storing users activities and notifications, similar to what instagram has. (when someone likes your post, when there's a new comment or someone you follow posted a new content).

It will be very space extensive to store all of these activities for every individual user.
for example if someone with 3k followers posted; that 3,000 new records added to the database.

Question :

To save space I want to store maximum of 20 records in the collection (Activity).

When inserting new record; if the collection size is 20 the oldest record (index 0) should be removed like a queue.. meaning only storing the 20 latest activities.

is there any easy way to achieve this with mongoose?

thanks.

Comment: Use $push with $slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something called "Capped Collections":

- [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) - Please read "Behavior" section in this docs because capped collections have some limitations.
- [Mongoose Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#capped)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.